# Server-side fetched data appears, disappears and re-appears on Vue 3 / Nuxt 3 production

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, vue-router

### Update - extra insights

Looking into the performance tab of Google Chrome, I noticed that the disappearing of elements happen whenever the network is requesting an asset.

For example:

1. The logo is there due to being loaded on server side
2. Client side fetches the logo asset
3. Logo disappears
4. Client side has finished fetching the logo
5. Logo re-appears

Although the client-side kicking in is expected behavior, I would still believe that the app would be smart enough to understand the logo asset is the same as the server side. Any chance I can avoid this disappearing of the content?

### Intro

In my Nuxt 3 / Vue 3 SSR project, I have a `server/api/prismic.js` file that fetches our application content from Prismic (Headless CMS).

Then, in our `pages/[...uid].vue` file, I fetch that data and render the slices.
This works magically; as in the website loads blazing fast.

However.. the problem is that I'm getting a glitch right before our dynamic page is finished loading. So I get the following:

1. Page loads
2. Page immediately contains components loaded with content
3. Page disappears
4. Page appears again with the same data

What unfortunately **doesn't** work: only fetching the data on a server-side. Because then I end up having a blank page.

The issue does **not** happen on `localhost:3000` tested with `yarn build && yarn start`, but only on the deployed version on Heroku.

I'm aware this issue is probably because the client is kicking in, but I was still wondering if anyone could help or guide me what the issue might be. Is this a Nuxt 3 issue? Or maybe something specific to `vue-router`?

### What I discovered

On app level, I also fetch from my `api/prismic` endpoint to fetch the navigation and footer content. I noticed that the navigation and footer also appear, disappear and re-appear; with the `navigation & footer ref` both still containing the same content content.

This removes a few theories that I had, such as the fact that passing an object to my dynamic component is the culprit.

### Code

`app.vue`

```
<template>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <Navigation :nav="navigation" />
    <main id="page">
      <NuxtPage :key="$route.path" />
    </main>
    <Footer :footer="footer" />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const { data: navigation } = await useFetch(
  '/api/prismic?type=single&uid=header',
  { key: 'header' },
)
const { data: footer } = await useFetch(
  '/api/prismic?type=single&uid=footer', 
  { key: 'footer' },
)
</script>
```

`server/api/prismic.js`

```
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const query = useQuery(event)
  const { repo, type, uid } = query
  const qTypes = {
    id: 'document.id',
    page: 'my.page.uid',
    single: 'document.type',
  }
  const { access_token, endpoint } = import.meta.env
  let params = { access_token }
  const prismicRef = await $fetch(endpoint, { params })
  params.ref = prismicRef.refs[0].ref
  params.q = `[[at(${qTypes[type] || 'document.id'}, "${uid}")]]`
  const document = await $fetch(`${endpoint}/documents/search`, { params })
  if (document.results && document.results.length > 0) {
    return document.results[0].data
  }
  return null
})
```

`pages/[...uid].vue`

```
<template>
  <div id="slices">
    <component
      v-for="(slice, index) in page.body"
      :is="slice.slice_type"
      :key="`${$route.path}-${index}`"
      :slice="slice"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
definePageMeta({ middleware: ['default'], pageTransition: { name: 'fade' } })
const route = useRoute()
const uid = ref(route.params.uid[0] || 'home')
const { data: page } = await useFetch(
  `/api/prismic?type=page&uid=${uid.value}`,
  { key: uid.value },
)
</script>
```

Comment: You know that your API will send every information about any user if someone knows their uid ?

Comment: The uid in this case does not provide any private content, it's literally just the unique ID of the route that I'm passing.

Comment: I think i have a similar experience. In Nuxt 2, it used to pass the SSR loaded content through to the front end, there was some communication between the front and back. In nuxt 3 it seems more like 2 seperate instances of the app, a server rendered version and a browser rendered version.

The weird thing is as you mention, localhost dev works fine, the issue only appears when it's deployed (in my case on AWS lambda)

Comment: @CadeEmbery Since you also have the issue in Nuxt 2, my theory that it's a bug related to Nuxt 3 not yet being final might be incorrect. Although I suppose I'll have to wait and see once Nuxt 3 is stable. Were you ever able to resolve the issue in Nuxt 2?

If not, I might have to create an issue on their Github.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with an icon plugin using SVG assets, I tried implementing a mechanism to choose whether the icon is rendered client side with lazy loading or server side (the logo for example), the result is just random, sometimes it render two times sometimes not at all with an error returning `null` for `asset not found`, I had to check `process.server` add some hacky conditions work with `onMounted`  to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally resolved the issue; here's some background:

In the time between my initial question and this answer, I already moved to using Nuxt SSG instead of SSR and encountered the exact same problem.

After a lot of playing around with Nuxt 3, I finally was able to find the real culprit: CloudFlare.

It ended up being CF's minification on the HTML code. CF was removing Vue's comment fragments such as `<!--]-->`, which apparently enables Vue 3 not to require a single root element.

Since those fragments got removed during minification, the app didn't react as it should've.

Before coming with this solution, I had already posted an [issue on Nuxt 3's repo](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues/7783), which contains full explanation on the issue.

Comment: You are my saviour. Thanks for that, was pulling me hairs out.